# how to connect Google Cloud Data loss Prevention with asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-cloud-dlp

I am trying to use Google cloud Dlp Api in asp.net web api.
to redact some information from an image file.

I installed Google.Apis.DLP.v2 nuget package.
and followed the url - 
[google Dlp c# request](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/redacting-sensitive-data-images?authuser=2#dlp-redact-image-csharp)

the url says the client as below

> DlpServiceClient client = DlpServiceClient.Create();

but i am not able to find DlpServiceClient class.
am i using the right nuget package?
i couldn't find any other code samples to see how dlp api works.

Answer (score 1):

Please consider [this coding sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dotnet-docs-samples/blob/master/dlp/api/DlpSample/RedactSamples.cs). For using class DlpServiceClient, you need to include Google.Cloud.Dlp.V2 package.